# SQL arranging vertical information horizontally

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Folks . I have run into an extremely unique situation but I am sure you people might have faced the same .

I have four tables . (they represent a user filling in a survey form)

```
SurveyFiller
------------

ID NAME  ORGANIZATION
1  AHMED  IBM

Questions
--------

ID Question
1  Did you like our event?
2  Will you come again?


    Answers
    -------

    ID Answers
    1  Yes
    2  No
    3  Maybe
    4  bla bla

QuestionAnswerMatrix
---------------------

ID SurveyFillerId QuestionId AnswerId
1     1              1            4
2     1              2           1
3     1              3            2
```

That is all . Now my client wants to see the survey results like the following

```
SurveyFIllerID  Name        Did you like our event?  Will you come again?
 1              Ahmed       yes                      No
```

I have no idea how to go about this , because in my tables I have got vertically arranged data , 
however the output wants the data to be horizontal .

Please aid me .

Comment: what if you have 10 long questions? do still want it to display vertically?

Comment: one more thing, do you want to list all the questions even if the user did not answer it?

Comment: mmm yeah . that is why i created such a structure. new questions can be added , and new answers. and the result should expand "horizontally"

Comment: hmm, ok. one more thing, your desired result does not match with the value of the `QuestionAnswerMatrix` from `Answers`

Comment: oh yes JW , thats just a mistake i must have made typing in a hurry . Let me read your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a dynamic query in which it will display all the questions available in the result list even if the user did not answer the question.

```
DECLARE @colList AS NVARCHAR(MAX), @sqlStatement AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

SELECT @colList = STUFF((SELECT DISTINCT ',' + QUOTENAME(Question) 
                    FROM Questions
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') ,1,1,'')


SET @sqlStatement = 
            'SELECT ID,Name, ' + @colList + ' 
             FROM 
             (
                SELECT  a.ID, 
                        a.Name,
                        b.Question,
                        d.Answers
                FROM    SurveyFiller a
                        CROSS JOIN Questions b
                        LEFT JOIN QuestionAnswerMatrix c
                            ON  a.ID = c.SurveyFillerId AND
                                b.ID = c.QuestionId
                        LEFT JOIN Answers d
                            ON  c.AnswerId = d.ID
                WHERE   a.ID = 1
             ) dta
             pivot 
             (
                MAX(Answers)
                FOR Question IN (' + @colList + ')
             ) pvt'

EXECUTE(@sqlStatement)
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1ec71/3)

OUTPUT (*something like this*)

```
╔════╦═══════╦═════════════════════════╦══════════════════════╗
║ ID ║ NAME  ║ DID YOU LIKE OUR EVENT? ║ WILL YOU COME AGAIN? ║
╠════╬═══════╬═════════════════════════╬══════════════════════╣
║  1 ║ AHMED ║ bla bla                 ║ Yes                  ║
╚════╩═══════╩═════════════════════════╩══════════════════════╝
```

Comment: if you remove `WHERE   a.ID = 1` it will display all the users in the table `SurveyFiller`.

Comment: JW , I can't overstate how much your help means . Thanks . It worked like a charm .

I hope I can too one day solve such issues solo . 

stay blessed.